# Python 3 http.server syntax error

Tags: python-3.4

Hi I try to set up my first simple Python http server. This is what I tried. Please help.

```
>>>import os
>>>os.chdir('/users/ds/my documents/pythonservers/frenchacademy')
>>>os.getcwd()
'C:\\users\\ds\\my documents\\pythonservers\\frenchacademy'
>>> python -m SimpleHTTPServer
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> -m SimpleHTTPServer
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> python -m http.server
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> -m http.server
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
--version
NameError: name 'version' is not defined
>>> python --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
python --version
NameError: name 'python' is not defined
>>> $ python -m http.server
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> python3 -m http.server
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> -m http.server
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> python3 -m http.server --help
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 5):

Fund the solution. As usually a stupid error. I had to put the command in the windows command line and not in python itself.